# How to get values back from an external function that requires interactivity?

Tags: bash, function, shell

One of the routines I frequently use is a check for valid arguments passed when invoking scripts. Ideally, I'd like to make these, and other, similar, routines external functions that I could call from any script, for handling these more trivial processes. But, I'm having trouble retrieving the values I need from said function(s), without making the process more complicated.

I have tried using command substitution (e.g., echoing the output of the external function into a variable name local to the calling script), which seems to at least work with simpler functions. However, working with this file checking function, requires the read command in a loop, and, thus, user interactivity, which causes the script to hang when trying to resolve the variable that function call is stored in:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a simple function I want to call from other scripts.
exist(){
  # If the first parameter passed is not a directory, then the input is 
  #+ invalid.
  if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    # Rename $1, so we can manipulate its value.
    userDir="$1"
    # Ask the user for new input while his input is invalid.
    while [ ! -d "$userDir" ]; do
      echo "\"$userDir\" does not exist."
      echo "Enter the path to the directory: "
      read userDir
      # Convert any tildes in the variable b/c the shell didn't get to
      #+ perform expansion.             
      userDir=`echo "$userDir" | sed "s|~|$HOME|"`
      done
    fi
}
exist "$1"
```

How can I retrieve the value of userDir in the calling script without adding (much) complexity?

Comment: Be cautious about not double quoting `"$1"` in the `if` test.

Comment: You must echo it and then have the caller of this function do command substitution. That's the only way.

Comment: Also, quote your variables and use `IFS= read -r userDir`.

Comment: Also, the `sed` line can replaced by `userDir=${userDir/\~/$HOME/}`.

Comment: Added the forgotten quotes. How do I go about echo'ing it and using command substitution. I've tried, but the way I've done it, the script hangs because the substitution cannot effectively take place because the function requires user interactivity. How does this help:`IFS= read -r userDir`

Comment: Variables are global unless declared otherwise. As long as `exist` is called in the same shell, you can simply access `$userDir` after it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the exist function interact with the user over stderr and still capture the variable with *command substitution*.  Let's take a simplified example:

```
exist() { read -u2 -p "Enter dir: " dir; echo "$dir"; }
```

The option `-u2` tells `read` to use file descriptor 2 (stderr) for interacting with the user.  This will continue to work even if stdout has been redirected via command substitution.  The option `-p "Enter dir: "` allows `read` to set the prompt and capture the user input in one command.

As an example of how it works:

```
$ d=$(exist)
Enter dir: SomeDirectory
$ echo "$d"
SomeDirectory
```

#### Complete example

```
exist() {
    local dir="$1"
    while [ ! -d "$dir" ]; do
        echo "'$dir' is not a directory." >&2
        read -u2 -p "Enter the path to the directory: " dir
    dir="${dir/\~/$HOME}"
    done
    echo "$dir"
}
```

As an example of this in use:

```
$ d=$(exist /asdf)
'/asdf' is not a directory.
Enter the path to the directory: /tmp
$ echo "new directory=$d"
new directory=/tmp
```

Notes:

1. There is no need for an `if` statement *and* a `while` loop.   The `while` is sufficient on its own.
2. Single quotes can be put in double-quoted strings without escapes.  So, if we write the error message as `"'$dir' is not a directory."`, escapes are not needed.
3. All shell variables should be double-quoted unless one wants them to be subject to word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: I think it finally works following this procedure. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why this works and the other methods I've tried have not. In the meantime, Thank You. I voted up, but I'm a noob so it doesn't count.

Comment: @GH05T The `-u2` option to `read` might be what makes the difference.

Comment: Yes. I think so. I've definitely gained a lot from this! (Thanks again) Among other things, on the importance of quoting parameters (though, I was only sloppy in my script b/c I was certain that none of my file names contain spaces or special chars, but I can see how this can quickly become a bad habit when scripting for someone else's files or machine), IFS, redirecting stderr, read options, and, of course, functions.

Comment: The one thing I'm still trying to figure out is that form of expansion/substitution you used on line 6 in the exist function `dir="${dir/\~/$HOME}"`, which was also mentioned by @redneb

Comment: @GH05T A feature of bash is _pattern substitution_.  It looks like `${parameter/old/new}` and it replaces the pattern `old` with `new`.  In our case, we use `${dir/\~/$HOME}`.   This replaces `~` with the value of the variable `$HOME`.  One tricky point is that `~` is a shell-active character and we want to match a literal `~`. Consequently, we  must escape the `~` with a backslash: `\~`.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat I'd say you can 'echo' to the user on stderr and echo your intended answer on stdout.
I had to rearrange a bit to get it working, but this is tested:

```
exist(){
    # If the first parameter passed is not a directory, then the input is
    #+ invalid.
    userDir="$1"
    if [ ! -d "$userDir" ]; then
        # Ask the user for new input while his input is invalid.
        while [ ! -d "$userDir" ]; do
            >&2 echo "\"$userDir\" does not exist."
            >&2 echo "Enter the path to the directory: "
            read userDir
        done
    else
        >&2 echo "'$1' is indeed a directory"
    fi
    echo "$userDir"
}
```

When I tested, I saved that to a file called exist.inc.func

Then I wrote another script that uses it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ./exist.inc.func

#Should work with no input:
varInCallingProg=$(exist /root)
echo "Got back $varInCallingProg"

#Should work after you correct it interactively:
varInCallingProg2=$(exist /probablyNotAdirOnYourSystem )
echo "Got back $varInCallingProg2"
```

Comment: Of course there's no requirement that you make it external and then `source` it. I just tend to do that with reusable functions.

Comment: I am just now grasping the utility of this, and I like the method. Thanks for taking the time to provide a solution. I've really learned a lot. This might not sound like much, but it hadn't yet occurred to me that: A) I could put all my functions in the same file (if appropriate), and B) source is used like import in Python (not that I have experience with Python or any language; I'm just getting started), and that all we are really doing when sourcing our .bashrc files is telling the bash program to import some functions. It's taken away some more of the mystery from the bigger picture.